# Compiling hello world in Ubuntu fails

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++

I have a hello world c++ file and When I compile I get some bogus error. It seems something is off with c++ setup.
Here is what I get:

```
root@localhost:/home/student/tmp/gios/pr4/part1# g++ -o hello example.cpp 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/ext/string_conversions.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6361,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from example.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/cstdio:133:11: error: '::rewind' has not been declared
   using ::rewind;
```

The file has following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

g++ version:

```
root@localhost:/home/student/tmp/gios/pr4/part1# g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I reinstalled `build-essentials` after purging without any luck. I get the same error I was getting before. Is there something I should do to set up header files?

Thanks.

Comment: The only things I can think of are (1) there is something in your build environment that is causing some kind of conditional `#define` to be triggered; or (2) something in your `libstdc++-7-dev` package got corrupted. I suggest reinstalling `libstdc++-7-dev` as a first step.

Comment: I purged gcc as well then reinstalling build-essentials fixed it.